# Can MongoDB be updated from 2.2 to 3.2 directly

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I would like to know whether it is possible to upload MongoDB from 2.2 to 3.2 without any intermediary upgrades. If it is possible please share a resource that can follow. I would like to know what things to looks out for when up grading

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/),

Upgrade Requirements

To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.2, you must be running a 3.0-series release.

To upgrade from a 2.6-series release, you must upgrade to the latest 3.0-series release before upgrading to 3.2. For the procedure to upgrade from the 2.6-series to a 3.0-series release, see Upgrade MongoDB to 3.0.